# Simulating Boolean Circuit with RAM

Tags: turing-machines, reference-request, runtime-analysis, circuits, boolean-algebra

**Statement:**
Every $T(n)$ size bounded Boolean circuit family, could be simulated with $(T(n))^2$ time bounded Random Access Turing Machine (RAM).

Could you please supply me with a reference to an article\ book that states the above?

I am willing to attach this statement in my article, without needing to prove it myself